# Facing 'refcnt: fd -1 < 0' error when SIGALRM throws exception in perl

Tags: perl

My perl script is exiting with error "refcnt: fd -1 < 0" whenever die exception is thrown in SIGALRM handler. How to resolve this issue ?

```
$ cat ~/alarm_error.pl
$SIG{ALRM}=sub{die};

# Kill the command1 if it runs more than 1s and move on to next command
alarm 1;
my $command1 = 'sleep 100';

open(CMD, "|($command1) < /dev/null");
eval{ close(CMD)};

my $command2 = 'sleep 1';
open(CMD, "|($command2) < /dev/null");
close(CMD);

$ perl ~/alarm_error.pl
refcnt: fd -1 < 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in the development branch of perl (5.31.1), so should appear in 5.32.0 in a month or two's time. From perl5311delta.pod:

> close() on a pipe now preemptively clears the PerlIO object from the
>   IO SV.  This prevents a second attempt to close the already closed
>   PerlIO object if a signal handler calls die() or exit() while close()
>   is waiting for the child process to complete. 
>   https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=122112.

Comment: Is there any work around for this issue till changes are release in 5.32.0 ?

Comment: @Naga, There are definitely alternatives to using signals (which are pretty drastic). For example, you could use `IO::Select`